# difficulty in moving around code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in the controller

```
def search 

if params[:name]
      response = client.get_games(params[:name])
      if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
        games = client.parser(response)
        unless games.empty?
          session[:games] = games
          redirect_to game_path(params[:name])
        end
      end
....
....
....
end
end
I have the following code written in my client

def get_games(name)
    find_games(CGI.escape(name))
 end
```

I am finding difficulties in moving some of the logic to the get_games method in my client. For example doing this does not work for me and i would like some suggestions on how i could go about or if i am doing things wrong

```
if params[:name]
  games = client.get_games(params[:name])
  unless games.empty?
    session[:games] = games
          redirect_to game_path(params[:name])
        end
      end
...
...
...
end
end

def get_games(name)
response = find_games(CGI.escape(name))
if response.is_a?(NET::HTTPSuccess)
return JSON.parse(response.body)
else 
return nil
end
end
```

The former case works but the latter does not work.Basically i just need help in moving the code inside the `def search` to client and have only the `redirect_to game_path(params[:name])` in my controller. Any help much appreciated

Comment: Is there any output? What is the response that gets returned?

Comment: HTTP::NotFound..for the latter case

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
response = client.get_games(params[:name])
```

in the first case. if get_games is a method form Client model, then most likely you should change

```
response = find_games(CGI.escape(name))
```

for

```
response = get_games(params[:name])
```

Hard to answer better without more code.